# I want the flex items to stack on top of each other, but it doesn't happen. I already used flex-start for both the containers and children

Tags: html, css, flexbox, tailwind-css

Seen below is a screenshot from codepen while I was testing flexboxes.

[image]

The thing is that **there are spaces between the flex children but I want to eliminate that.** I have the html and css below. Can anyone help, or is this something that is natural to flexboxes and that I should use something else?

html:

```
<div class="border h-full m-0">
  <div id="stock-div" class="lg:calc-w-3/10 h-full text-center border m-0 flex flex-wrap items-start">
  <h2 class="text-center text-base w-full border m-0">Stocks</h2>
  <p class="border m-0">Flex Item 2</p>
</div></div>
```

css

```
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}

.flex {
 display: flex;
}

.flex-wrap {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.border {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.w-full {
  width: 100%;
}

.h-\[300px\] {
  height: 300px;
}

.flex-row {
  flex-direction: row;
}

.flex-grow {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.align-start {
  align-self: start
}

.items-start {
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.m-0 {
  margin: 0;
}

.h-full {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace the `flex-wrap` by `flex-col` to set the flex direction and probably add `items-start` (as you already did, but the effect will be different due to the direction) and maybe `justify-start` to get the result you want.

See [tailwind play example](https://play.tailwindcss.com/eSjBbioZOJ)

Comment: Yep, I also just realized that it's normal properties of flexbox and did it like you advised. Now it works!